# Compiling CARMEN Nav toolkit on Ubuntu 10.04

Tags: compiling

I'm a beginner to Ubuntu and I've been trying to install some robotics toolkits to be used on a Powerbot that I'm working on. I'm currently trying to install CARMEN Navigation toolkit and I have been following [these directions in the Ubuntu Wiki](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/carmen#1004lts) in order to go step by step. My procedure was as follows:

1. Import canlib.h in /usr/include
2. Install gtk+-2.0 through: sudo apt-get install libgtk2.0-*
3. Install additional packages (failed to install libwrap0-deb: E: Couldn't find package libwrap0-deb). Otherwise all other packages were installed.
4. According to the link I specified, they specified a hack where you comment out lines 274 to 286 in the configure file so that the system does not look for libgdk_imlib.a.
5. I ran ./configure and I got the following output:

   ```
   Using $CC as gcc...
   Found processor i686.
   Congratulations. You are running Linux.
   Found kernel 2.6.32-71-generic.
   This doesn't look like SuSE!
   Searching for linux kernel headers... found at /usr/src/linux-headers-2.6.32-71-generic/include
   Searching for canlib... Found canlib header at /usr/include/canlib.h
   Searching for GTK... found, version 2.20.1
   Searching for joystick... found at /usr/include/linux/joystick.h

   It looks like this is a system include, so I won't add it to the standard
   include path. Adding partial system include paths is usually a recipe for
   disaster. If this is the wrong thing to do, you could add the following
   line to Makefile.vars:
   JOYSTICK_INCLUDE = -I/usr/include/linux/joystick.h

   Searching for tcpd.h... not found
   Looks like your system does not support access control.
   Sorry about adding security holes.
   Searching for jpeglib.h... found
   Searching for zlib.h... found
   Searching for ImageMagick (Wand)... not found
   Searching for Java... not found
   Searching for doxygen... found
   Searching for SWIG... not found
   Should the C++ tools be installed for CARMEN: [Y/n] y
   Should the old laser server be used instead of the new one: [y/N] n

   Type the install prefix to use for public installs, or hit enter to keep the
   default as /usr/local. (This prefix is not currently used by any rules.)

   Install path [/usr/local/]: 

   You must have Linux kernel 2.0.20 to compile:
   Nomadic Technologies XR4000

   These are the robot types CARMEN currently supports:
   1. ActiveMedia Pioneer I
   2. ActiveMedia Pioneer II
   3. iRobot ATRV
   4. iRobot ATRV-JR
   5. iRobot B21R
   6. Scout
   7. OrcBoard v.4 
   8. OrcBoard v.5 (Experimental)
   9. Segway RMP
   10. *

   Please select which robots you wish to compile base modules for.
   e.g., 1, 2, 6 would compile support for both Pioneer types and a Scout.
   Hit enter to compile them all, or type "none" to compile no base module
   support, for example, if you will be working exclusively in simulation.

   Robot numbers [*]: 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8 

   Compiling base support for: pioneer rflex scout orc4 orc5
   ```

What I did not like was the fact that tcpd.h was **not found** when according to the link, it should have been found. I ran the make file in any case and this is what I got when it tried to make the global functions of CARMEN

```
    ****************************************************************
    * Module  : GLOBAL
    * Comment : CARMEN global functions
    ****************************************************************

    --> Starting make
    ---- Assigning dependencies in GLOBAL
    ---- Compiling global.c to global.o (cc)
    cc1: warnings being treated as errors
    global.c: In function ‘carmen_get_host’:
    global.c:411: error: ignoring return value of ‘fscanf’, declared with attribute     warn_unused_result
    make[3]: *** [global.o] Error 1
    exit: 7: Illegal number: -1
    make[2]: *** [libraries] Error 2
    make[1]: *** [phase1] Error 2
    exit: 1: Illegal number: -1
    make: *** [phase1] Error 2
```

Please, can anyone help me out here? I don't know what these errors mean and I don't know how to correct them! Should I resort to an even older version of Ubuntu?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not know the tool in question, but probably could be useful:

1. According to `apt-search`, `tcpd.h` is provided by the package `libwrap0-dev` (there seems to be a typo, "de**b**" instead of "de**v**");
2. About the error, the compilation stops because somewhere in the configure or Makefile `gcc` has been requested to treat all warnings as errors. The specific warning is one that could be *normally* ignored; you can proceed two ways:

   - edit the file `global.c` and, in line 411, put a `(void)` in front to the call to `fscanf` that is erroring out, or
   - edit the Makefile(s) and find where the option `-Werror` is added, and remove it. Then keep fingers crossed.

The best way would be to contact the authors of the software and reporting the problem.

BTW, going back to old releases is not a recommended thing to do; it would be a lot better to work with the developers to adapt the software to a modern one. It is more work on the short term, a lot less on the long one.

Good luck!

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot for your help! I have tried your first solution of putting fscanf(); in line 411 but then I got another error telling me that fscanf has too few arguments. So I tried your second solution, but I could not find -Werror in any of the makefiles that I am attempting to run.

Comment: Maybe I was not clear... in line 411 you should have `fscanf(whatever);` --- you should change it to `(void)fscanf(whatever)` (it's C idiom to discard the result value of the funcion). If you do not have `-Werror`, then probably is one of the `-Wsomething` defined here: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html --- But it can get quite complex quite fast